# <div>s to float/overlay above other elements in css

Tags: html, css, css-float, overlay

This question refers to my web-page at this address: http://www.acehscmaths.com/welcome/testhome

When you click on the "charts" menu option (next to the logo right at the top), it pulls down more menu options, this then causes the whole page to be pushed downwards. Is there anyone I can apply a CSS setting to these drop-down elements so that they overlay above the existing content (so as not to push the whole page down).

I'm not sure which bits of code I should copy, so I have just copied the particular menu in question:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="side-bar-wrapper collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

        <ul class="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="charts.html" class="is-dropdown-menu">
                    <span class="badge pull-right"></span>
                    <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> Charts
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="charts.html#area_chart_anchor">
                            <i class="icon-random"></i>
                            Area Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="charts.html#circle_chart_anchor">
                            <i class="icon-bullseye"></i>
                            Circular Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="charts.html#bar_chart_anchor">
                            <i class="icon-signal"></i>
                            Bar Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="charts.html#line_chart_anchor">
                            <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
                            Line Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="side-bar-wrapper collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

        <ul class="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="newquestion">
                    <i class="icon-question"></i> Question
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="side-bar-wrapper collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

        <ul class="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="newnotes">
                    <i class="icon-book"></i> Study Notes
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the following adjustments in your css should fix the issue and maintain the fluid layout of your page.

```
.side-menu {
   position:relative;
}
.side-menu li ul {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  width:100%;
}
```

It may need a little adjustment but should sort the issue.

Comment: Ah brilliant. This works great. Thank you. Now I just need to add some styling with shadows etc.

Comment: Thanks again for this. I think, however, the styling is broken when doing this - please could you help me find out why and how to fix. Thanks again for your patience. I'd like it to look like www.acehscmaths.com/welcome/testhome2 but with the dropdown effect (i.e. not moving other divs) of www.acehscmaths.com/testhome - there is only one difference in the CSS between the 2 versions, the version with the dropdown but poorer styling has the following CSS added: 

.side-menu {
    position:relative;
}
.side-menu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99;
    width:100%;
}

Comment: No, no problem at all! You could add the border radius and box-shadow properties from '.side-menu' to '.side-menu li ul', however, with the lighter background you'll inevitably lose the desired depth I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks, I've just made that change and it looks much better now. Thanks again for all the help - you're clearly a CSS expert - so if you think of any other way to make it look nicer then please let me know. I think it looks pretty good now (updated at the above URL - http://www.acehscmaths.com/welcome/testhome). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To **side-bar-wrapper .side-menu > li > ul** (your **ul** under **li** with class active) add

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
width: 350px;
```

You can chose smaller z-index. I set width to 350px becouse it seemed to be about the same, but you should set it your way.

Comment: I think `position: absolute;` is already enough if no other elements use z-index

Comment: In my test without z-index drop down remains hidden so I suggested z-index also.

Comment: Hi, thanks. This works. I've now implemented this but it has caused another issue. That menu is responsively designed/sized, so having a fixed width here breaks the flow. Any idea if there's a way I can fix that as well please? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For the hidden part:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 123;
width: 293px;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px #000; /*for extra snazzy looks*/
```

You'll need the z-index as there appear to be other things on your page using absolute positioning.

Comment: Hi, thanks. This works. I've now implemented this but it has caused another issue. That menu is responsively designed/sized, so having a fixed width here breaks the flow. Any idea if there's a way I can fix that as well please? Thanks again.